# How to clear the content or values of variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to know whether there is a way to keep the name of variables but erase the content of these variables. I do not want to reiterate the definition of these variables. I would like to erase the content of variables to avoid mixing the data from different runs.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I would rather suggest creating a function or a script, which does the work and calling that for each run.

Comment: I have to copy some data from different places. Off course I can parse files. I noticed that this kind of functionality is interesting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its messy and I wouldn't do it, but I "think" this is what your after:

```
function resetBaseWorkspace 
  vars = evalin ( 'base', 'whos' );
  for ii=1:length(vars)
    evalin ( 'base', sprintf ( '%s = []', vars(ii).name ) );
  end
end
```

Run the above function when you want to clear the vars in the base workspace.

To reset structs - you could use the above theory (but its very messy code...)...

So why dont you save a mat file containing your structs with "empty" fields and load it at the start of your process?

Or use functions instead?

Comment: in my case variables contain nested structs

Comment: You want to clear every field in a struct?  Or create empty structs?

Comment: I want to clear every field. I want to avoid redefining of fields.